# Host-based ssh authentication using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have installed the ssh2 package for node but can not get the host based authentication working.

```
var Connection = require('./node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2');
var conn = new Connection();

conn.on('ready', function() {
    conn.exec('cmviewcl -v -f line', function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;

        stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
        }).on('close', function() {
            console.log('Stream :: close');
            conn.end();
        }).on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
        }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
        });
    });
}).connect({
    host: 'server',
    port: 22,
    username: 'root'
});
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased
    at Connection._tryNextAuth (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:1010:13)
    at onUSERAUTH_FAILURE (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:2449:8)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:141:5)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Parser.parsePacket (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Parser.js:488:12)
    at Parser.execute (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Parser.js:249:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/bis/node/node_modules/bis-package/node_modules/ssh2/lib/Connection.js:536:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
```

We use host based authentication which allows us password free logins. In Perl I use the following:

```
my( $SSH ) = "/usr/bin/ssh -t -o PreferredAuthentications=hostbased 2>/dev/null";
$run->run( map { qq{$SSH $_ "$CMD"} } @hosts );
```

I am not sure how I could do that with the nodejs [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) package.
Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for hostbased authentication yet. I plan to add support for it in the upcoming next major release. The relevant issue is [here](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/193).

Comment: Not yet, I did a pretty large [refactor](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/tree/rewrite) recently and am in the process of writing tests. After that I am planning on adding support for hostbased auth, PuTTY keys, and possibly support for some more openssh extensions.